# JDBC connection pooling with Struts 2

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using connection pooling in Struts2 application but after some request, I am not getting any result even though I am closing the connection in our application. Please give me proper solution.

Context.xml

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/abbas"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="myuser"
          password="pass@123"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.14.65/abbas"
          maxActive="15"
          maxIdle="3"/>
```

Comment: To give you a proper solution, you must show your code.

Comment: this is my context.xml <Resource name="jdbc/abbas"

auth="Container"

type="javax.sql.DataSource"

username="myuser"

password="pass@123"

driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.14.65/abbas"

maxActive="15"

maxIdle="3"/>

Comment: Please check following tread it may help you.   1.) http://www.coderanch.com/t/621758/Struts/JNDI-Connection-pooling-Struts   2) http://jaiswaltraining.com/struts/ch5.php

Comment: Please show your code, especially the part closing the connection...

Comment: In general you don't get a connection a from pool, then return the connection back to the pool. You don't close the connection. Check is you are closing the connection to db instead of returning it back to pool.